# AJAX database update

Tags: javascript, ajax, database

This is my first ajax attempt. I want to pass id variable to ajax function and update my database. When I run this code everything looks fine. Id in alert is correct but my database is not updated. Please tell me what is wrong with my code.

My api.php:

```
<?php 
include 'config.php';
$page_id =$_POST['page_id'];                        
$result = mysql_query("SELECT State FROM alarm WHERE ID_Alarm = $page_id ");

if($result==Off){
$result = mysql_query("UPDATE alarm SET State = On WHERE ID_Alarm = $page_id");  
}else{
$result = mysql_query("UPDATE alarm SET State = Off WHERE ID_Alarm = $page_id");
                        }
    ?>
```

My js function with ajax:

```
    function changeImage(e) {

    $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "web/api.php",

          data:"page_id="+e.id,
          success: function(data) 
          {
              alert(e.id);

          }, error: function()
          {
              alert("something went wrong");
          }
       });

                }
```

html:

```
<div id=\"$i\" class=\"alarmon\" onclick=\"changeImage(this)\"> </div>
```

Comment: Your AJAX is sending the `id` parameter, but PHP is expecting `page_id`. The parameter names need to match.

Comment: That was mistake in my post. With page_id still doesn't work.

Comment: You need to read a tutorial on how to use `mysql` functions in PHP. You need to call `mysql_fetch_XXX` to fetch the data, it's not in `$result` itself.

Comment: A bit off topic: i noticed you're placing `$_POST` variables directly in your sql query. This poses a big security risk, since anyone can put anything they want into a `$_POST` variable. A malicious user could for example create a request with the variable `$_POST["page_id"]` containing `"5 OR 1=1"`, which would result in an SQL query that updates every record in the table, instead of just that one you wanted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would update your PHP file as follows:

**UPDATE:** Try enclosing On and Off in single quotes

```
<?php 
include 'config.php';
$page_id =$_POST['page_id'];                        
$result = mysql_query("SELECT State FROM alarm WHERE ID_Alarm = $page_id ");

$state = mysql_result($result, 0);

if($state == "Off"){
  $result = mysql_query("UPDATE alarm SET State = 'On' WHERE ID_Alarm = $page_id");  
}
else{
  $result = mysql_query("UPDATE alarm SET State = 'Off' WHERE ID_Alarm = $page_id");
}
?>
```

The first error I saw is that `Off` was not a constant, so it has to be enclosed in double or single quotes.

Also $result will be a resource not a string.

I hope this helps.

Comment: "UPDATE: Try enclosing On and Off in single quotes"  Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a `SELECT` and `IF`. You can update the table in one query:

```
mysql_query("UPDATE alarm 
             SET State = IF(State = 'On', 'Off', 'On')
             WHERE ID_Alarm = $page_id");
```

Comment: Thanks it looks nice but doesn't solve the problem. :)

Comment: I just fixed the missing quotes that @YoelNunez pointed out in his answer. I'm assuming that your `State` column is a string.

Comment: State column is a string. It works now with this quotes. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

Enclose the $page_id in single quote like this '$page_id'. Your Code will be as follow

```
$result = mysql_query("UPDATE alarm SET State = On WHERE ID_Alarm = '$page_id'");
```

now run the code Id will be save to database.

Comment: You have not even enclosed the on in single parenthesis. Furthermore, mysql_query has been deprecated in PHP4. Use musqli instead.

    $result = mysqli_query("update alarm set State = 'On' where ID_Alarm = '$page_id'");